# Java PriorityQueue: how to heapify a Collection with a custom Comparator?

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

For example, given a List of Integer `List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(5,4,5,2,2)`, how can I get a `maxHeap` from this List in `O(n)` time complexity?

The naive method:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
for (Integer i : list) {
    maxHeap.offer(i);
}
```

However, the time complexity is `O(nlogn)`.

We can trigger the heapify method by using the following constructor:

```
PriorityQueue<Integer> maxHeap = new PriorityQueue<>(list);
```

The time complexity is `O(n)`. However, it forces me to use the **natural order** which is the **minHeap**.

My Question:

How can I construct a PriorityQueue by heapifying a Collection with custom Comparator?

Ref:
[Java doc of PriorityQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html)

PS:
@user207421
Heapify algorithm can transform any unsorted array into a heap in `O(n)` time, not `O(nlogn)`. [There are many articles about heapify](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/), also in CLRS's Introduction to Algorithms Page 159, build a heap from any unsorted array is `O(n)`. And heap is also not a sorted array. It's a complete tree with heap property which can be encoded in array.

Comment: At least in my version of the JDK, `heapify` is only called in `initFromCollection`, `bulkRemove` and `readObject`. None of those methods make sense to call here. For a quick and dirty solution, I would use reflection to set the comparator. Otherwise, roll your own implementation.

Comment: If the input collection is already sorted the complexity is *O(N)*. However if it isn't sorted, it has to be sorted, so the time must be *O(N log(N))*, whichever way you cut it. You can't get sorting for nothing. Question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @user207421 Have you ever known the heapify algorithm? It can take any unsorted array into a heap in `O(n)` time not `O(nlog n)`. By the way, heap is also not a fully sorted array.

Comment: @user207421 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/ There are bunch of articles about heapify which is `O(n)` to heapify any unsorted array.

Comment: @maplemaple I've been using heapsort since 1971. The claims in your links have exactly the same status as my claim above: they are unrefereed Internet junk. If you were to quote Dijkstra or Knuth or Wirth or Hoare or Sedgewick at me it would be another matter. I see from my library that Sedgewick states that heapify can be *O(N)* in most cases, but not in all.

Comment: Heap construction from the beginning can be ```O(n)``` as stated by Sedgewick: "Sink-based heap construction uses fewer than 2N compares and
fewer than N exchanges to construct a heap from N items." However, creating an empty PQ and then inserting into it one-by-one requires ```O(n logn)``` time complexity. Priority Queue implementation of Java doesn't accept a custom ```Comparator``` and ```Collection``` at the same time. So OP asks, how can we create a PQ in ```O(n)``` with our custom ```Comparator``` so that it is max-heap not min-heap (as default).

Comment: @user207421  Muhteva has cited the argument of Sedgewick. In CLRS's Introduction to Algorithms Page 159, build a heap from any unsorted array is O(n)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## If you don't mind some hack

According to the [java doc of PriorityQueue(PriorityQueue)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html#PriorityQueue-java.util.PriorityQueue-)

> Creates a PriorityQueue containing the elements in the specified priority queue. This priority queue will be ordered according to the same ordering as the given priority queue.

So we can extend `PriorityQueue` as `CustomComparatorPriorityQueue` to hold the desired comparator and the Collection we need to heapify. Then call new `PriorityQueue(PriorityQueue)` with an instance of `CustomComparatorPriorityQueue`.

Below is tested to work in Java 15.

```java
import java.util.*;

public class CustomComparatorPriorityQueue<T> extends PriorityQueue<T> {
    private Collection<T> wrapped;

    public static <U> PriorityQueue<U> create(Collection<U> wrapped, Comparator<U> custom) {
        return new PriorityQueue<U>(new CustomComparatorPriorityQueue<>(wrapped, custom));
    }

    private CustomComparatorPriorityQueue(Collection<T> wrapped, Comparator<T> custom) {
        super(custom);
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] toArray() {
        return wrapped.toArray();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> a = Arrays.asList(3, 6, 4, 8, 1, 9);
        PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = CustomComparatorPriorityQueue.create(a, Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder().reversed());
        Integer b;
        while ((b = pq.poll()) != null) {
            System.out.println(b);
        }
    }

    // Override to don't allow other purpose...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to implement Max Heap via Min Heap: multiply each number in the collection by -1, then heapify the new collection into a Min Heap, and when we retrieve the number from the heap, also multiply by -1 to get the original number.